# Illegal nesting with SASS everytime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compiler-errors, sass, nested, nanoc

I’m trying to create my own website and I’m using Nanoc. I’m also writing my files in HAML and SASS. 

When I’m writing into my SASS file, I always have the error

```
Haml::SyntaxError: Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal
```

when I compile (`nanoc compile`).

 My sass files are in `/content/css` and I would like they go in `/output/css`

The thing I don’t understand is that if I put spaces or if I put a tab, it doesn’t compile. The only thing which works is when I don’t put any spaces or tabs. It compiles but the CSS in output doesn’t work.

I looked here before : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nanoc/UI4VccZCDD4 but it doesn't correct my compilation error.


I let my `style.sass` file and my `Rules` file below.

What is causing this issue and how can I resolve it?

```
div.title
  width: 80%
  background-color: #b7b8b2
```

If I put no spaces before `width` and `background`, it compiles but doesn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'compass'
Compass.add_project_configuration 'config.rb'   # when using Compass 0.10

### Compile rules
compile '/content/css/*' do
    filter :sass, Compass.sass_engine_options # add the second parameter for Compass
end

compile '*' do
  if item.binary?
    # don’t filter binary items
  else
    filter :haml
    layout 'default'
  end
end

### Route rules
route '/content/css/*' do
  #'/style.css'
  # item.identifier.chop + '.css' #so that the /content/stylesheet.sass item is compiled in sass
  unless item.identifier.start_with?('/content/css/_') # for partials
      item.identifier.gsub(/\/$/, '') + '.css'
  end
end

route '*' do
  if item.binary?
    # Write item with identifier /foo/ to /foo.ext
    item.identifier.chop + '.' + item[:extension]
  else
    # Write item with identifier /foo/ to /foo/index.html
    item.identifier + 'index.html'
  end
end

### Layout rules
layout '*', :haml
```

Comment: What version of nanoc are you using? A bug related to this problem was fixed recently, so upgrading may help.

Comment: I'm using Nanoc 3.6.4.
I made an update of Nanoc using the command `gem update nanoc`
Now, when I make the command `gem list`, I have 'nanoc (3.6.5, 3.6.4)' but the problem is unfortunately still here; it doesn't compile.
I just completely uninstalled nanoc and reinstalled it but the problem is not solved. I don't know where the compilation problem comes from...

Comment: Do you use Bundler? In that case, make sure you run `bundle up` and check that the Gemfile contains nanoc 3.6.5.

Comment: This also seems to be a Haml issue to me, rather than Sass. Can you share the `crash.log` and your default layout?

Comment: I'm not using Bundler. Should I?

Comment: Here is my `crash.log`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JZXfQtLe

Comment: Here is my `default.haml`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UnVd9UHD

Comment: I tried to make another `default.haml`file with nothing in it. I have the same error. I also downloaded another nanoc project on a GitHub repo and it works. So the mistakes comes from my files but I can't see where...

Comment: It seems like the :haml filter is run on stylesheets, which is not what you want (you want `:sass` instead). Can you share your Rules file?

Comment: I put my Rules file at the beginning of the topic ;)

Comment: Oops, didn’t see that. Your problem is probably that the CSS file is not matched by the first rule, but rather by the catch-all rule, and therefore it gets the Haml layout applied. What is the filename of the Sass file? If it’s content/css/something, then the first rule should match '/css/*' instead of '/content/css/*' (content is superfluous).

Comment: Your solution was the good one, ddfreyne! :)
I changed /css/* instead of /content/css/ and it works!
Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0):

The CSS compilation rule has an error. It should say

`compile '/css/*'`

instead of

`compile '/content/css/*'`

Item identifiers do not start with `/content`.